# Can Fourier transform help to solve homogeneous ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-transform

with ordinary differential equation
$$(\frac{\hbar}{\gamma})^2\frac{d}{dt}c(t)+2i\delta(\frac{\hbar}{\gamma})^2\frac{d^2}{dt^2}c(t)+c(t)=0$$

I would like to try on Fourier transformation to solve for this 2nd order homogeneous linear ordinary differential equation.

So my thought process was,
$$-2i\delta(\frac{\hbar}{\gamma})^2\to a_1 (complex number)$$
$$(\frac{\hbar}{\gamma})^2 \to a_2(complexnumber)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\to\boldsymbol A$$
and the eigenfunction of operator $\frac{d}{dt}$, the $\boldsymbol A$
$$(\int dw\exp(iwt)\to \boldsymbol V,\int dt\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(-iwt)\to \boldsymbol V^{-1},$$ these are the matrix contains eigenstates, and the matrix contains eigen value in diagonal way is
$$\boldsymbol D$$

Thus represents ODE as
$$a_2\boldsymbol A^2c(t)+a_1\boldsymbol Ac(t)+c(t)=0$$
and
$$a_2\boldsymbol V\boldsymbol D^2\boldsymbol V^{-1}+a_1\boldsymbol V \boldsymbol D \boldsymbol V^{-1} + \boldsymbol Vc(w)\boldsymbol V^{-1}=0 \iff \boldsymbol V[a_2\omega^2c(\omega)+a_1\omega c(\omega)+c(\omega)]=0$$

The thing that came up to my mind is that All differential equation that I had tried with fourier transformation was inhomogeneous or PDE. At this point I am lost what to do to get the solution.

Sould I solve for $\omega$? if then, what should I do next?

Comment: Assuming $\delta$ isn't the Dirac delta function, the standard way to start is to look at solutions of the form $e^{at}$ and to see what that imposes on $a$. You ought to get two values that work, and from there you can build your linear combinations.